# How can I retrieve the text next to a radio button when scraping HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

Right now, I'm using SimpleHTMLDOM and trying to scrape some HTML.  This is the HTML that I'm retrieving:

```
<form action="playtrivia.jsp" name="playtrivia">
    <input name="triviaid" type="hidden" value="452051"><input name="categoryid" type="hidden" value="0">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><div id="title"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4"><hr width="75%"></td></tr>
        <tr><td valign="top" colspan="4" align="center"><br></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><div id="title">Saturday's Secret Seat</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img height="1" width="5" src="spacer.gif"></td>
        <td><input name="numanswers" type="hidden" value="3"><div id="subtitle">What's today's Secret Seat?</div><br>
            <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1885233">W03<br>
            <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1885235">Q46<br>
            <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1885234">R90<br></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td colspan="3"><br><img height="1" width="10" src="spacer.gif"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is the code I've got so far that accurately gets the hidden values and the list of radio buttons with their values, but I also need to get the text that comes immediately after the button (e.g. "W03", "Q46", and "R90")

```
$links = array();
foreach($html->find('input[name="answer"]') as $a) {
    echo $a . "<br>";
    $links[] = $a->value;
}

foreach($html->find('input[type="hidden"]') as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot figure out how to get that text.

Comment: Since that text is the value of the `TextNode` immediately following that input element, I think a simple call to `nextSibling` on the input element should suffice to get that text node.

Comment: @CBroe, unfortunately that won't work, the next detected node will be `<br/>`

Comment: Try something like `$html->find('input[name="answer"]', 0)->parent()->find('text');` wich will give you all texts inside that last td node, then hopefully you can filter and get what you want...

Comment: @Enissay: So SimpleHtmlDOM does _not_ follow official DOM specifications then …? (Well better to say DOM _nomenclature_ maybe, since in DOM nextSibling is a property, not a method. But still bad IMHO.)

Comment: @Enissay: All I get with that is: `Fatal error:  Call to a member function parent() on a non-object in /path/secretseat/index.php on line 84
`

Comment: @CBroe, indeed it is bad... Waiting for a big update or a better alternative :>

Comment: @nexxai? dont forget the `, 0` argument, calling `parent()` on an array won't work of course...

Comment: @Enissay I copied it exactly how you wrote it - that's the error that it's giving.

Comment: @nexxai, well that means `find()` found nothing... Maybe consider posting your full code on pastebin.com so I can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Here is a simple idea, if it is ok for you, just try it.Personally I never used such texts besides the radio buttons.:)
just append the texts to the "value" attribute of each radio button like:

```
 <input name="answer" type="radio" value="1885234-R90" />R90
```

Now you can receive the value and split the value by '-' using explode() function  in php!!
example:
if $ a contains: 1885234-R90

```
$ b=explode ('-', $ a);
$ b [0] will hold 1885234 and
$ b [1] will hold R90
```

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't have access to the original HTML generator, and the people who do have made it clear that they're not changing anything.

Comment: Oh..!! Ok.We can expect some others to help u.Meanwhile ill comment here if I got any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simple won't let you get at that text node but [this one will](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/):

```
require_once('advanced_html_dom.php');
$html = '<input name="answer" type="radio" value="1885233">W03<br>';
$doc = str_get_html($html);
echo $doc->find('input[name=answer]', 0)->next->text;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring out the answer using some likely non-standard ways of doing things, but it works.  The first thing to clarify is that the original HTML snippet I posted wasn't the full page being scraped, so I ended up having to come up with a solution that would work with the whole page.

After using SimpleHTMLDOM to parse the HTML into blocks of TDs, I just had it explode() out the text into usable chunks in an array (I had originally added the tabbing in the above snippet in an effort to make things more readable; the actual HTML was much uglier and difficult to read at first).

```
$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('td') as $a) {
    $td[$i] = $a->plaintext;
    // echo $td[$i] . " Round " . $i . "<br>";          // Uncomment this line if they change the HTML to figure out which TD they moved the secret seat data to
    $i++;
}

//echo $td[26];

$seats = explode("\r\n", $td[26]);                      // Then update the array number here with the round you found in the previous foreach

$i = 1;
$links = array();
foreach($html->find('input[name="answer"]') as $a) {
    echo $a . $seats[$i] . "<br>\r\n";

    $links[] = $a->value;
    $i++;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who help me at least get pointed in the right direction.